# Is it safe to use eslint cache during development and during docker build for production?

Tags: node.js, docker, caching, eslint

Is it safe to use eslint cache during development and during docker build for production? Will I not miss some errors?

Comment: I'm not sure what your concern is. ESLint will only work as well as you make it. You need to tell it which files to scan and what rules to follow. If you omit a file or a rule you actually want, then you won't errors that you expect to see. With that said, you should most likely be using ESLint even with incomplete config, since it's easier to just add few more files and rules when you have linting as part of your build pipeline.

Comment: @VLAZ my concern is that if I change one file and for example got some cyclo import to another file, will it be catched if the other file is in the cache. I’m not sure if eslint will check all files for cyclo error after 1 change

Comment: What cache do you refer to? ESLint runs whenever you set it up to run and it will scan the files you tell it to scan. If you tell it to scan `file.js` it would always scan the latest version of `file.js` that is found on the file system. If you have something that somehow prevents the FS to supply you with the latest version of the file, then you might get a problem but that will not be constrained to ESLint but anything that will be reading the file. Since this is presumably part of your build pipeline, then your final artefact will be out of date anyway.

Comment: @VLAZ I'm referring to --cache flag of eslint, as I can see it just dumps files, that was scanned by it to the cache file